# Encoding a field result coming from a query

Tags: mysql, django, unicode, django-views, mysql-error-1064

In Django, I´m using an external command for throw a query against MySQL. All is getting great until I recover a field with utf-8 characters (kind of Cami**ó**n). In that point I can´t go through to the queryset anymore and MySQL returns

```
'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xf3' in position 34: ordinal not in range(128)
```

My code is the next one:

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
query = "SELECT * FROM " + table_name + " ORDER BY " + "1"
cursor.execute(query)

rows = cursor.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    result = []
    for field in row:
        print field
        result += [str(field)]
```

How can I avoid this situation?
Thanks Mates...

EDITED:
It works through `field = unicode(field).encode("utf-8", "replace")`

Comment: Calling and replace the original field string for the next one works...
 field = unicode(field).encode("utf-8", "replace")

Comment: Why are you doing this? Why aren't you using Django models?

Comment: Hahahaha... really long history... I almost get crazy trying to solve it... LOL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the below line at the beginning of your python script

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It´s a Django Project. Could I use it anyway?
Whatever, I found a solution which I can use directly in my view in my view. Check my update. Thanks Mate.

Answer (score 0):

Calling and replace the original field string for the next one works... field = unicode(field).encode("utf-8", "replace")